# Open Ria Services Where is AuthenticationService.EndLogin

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a silverlight app that I am trying to port to open silver, it uses openria services and the AuthenticationService.EndLogin function.

According to the metadata, the dll, namespace, class and signature are

```
Assembly OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.dll, v2.0.5.0 
namespace OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices
public abstract class AuthenticationService : INotifyPropertyChanged
protected internal abstract LoginResult EndLogin(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
```

I grabbed this code from here, but cannot find that function or that DLL, am I missing something?

https://github.com/OpenRIAServices/OpenRiaServices

Comment: You can try to download the [RIAServices.Silverlight package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.Silverlight/4.2.0), AuthenticationService.EndLogin requires the assembly [System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/wcf-ria/ff457889(v=vs.91)), you need to add a reference to this assembly.

Comment: I want the source code to this assembly
packages\OpenRiaServices.Client.Core.4.4.0.3\lib\sl50\OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.Web.dll

Comment: You can download it from [here](https://nuget.info/packages/RIAServices.Silverlight/4.2.0)(Contents-(lib\sl40).

Comment: That is just the dll for msft Ria services, I am looking for the source for Open Ria services so I can rebuild it on open silver.

Comment: [The link](https://github.com/OpenRIAServices/OpenRiaServices#nuget-packages) you provided all contain the relevant nuget packages, you need to download them all. [OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.Web.dll](https://nuget.info/packages/OpenRiaServices.Client.Core/5.0.1)